# How delete data in table on button click?

Tags: javascript, html, json

Here I have created an HTML page that has one form and table that displays data filled by using the form. But When I clicked on the delete button that row cannot be deleted from the table. I think I did something cheap mistake but I tried a lot and failed to find that caused console also did not shows any error, please someone tries to help me

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/Css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="/Js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/Js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

    <title>Registration Form</title>
    <style>
        .compulsory {
            color: red;
        }
    </style>
    <script>
        var studentList = [];
        function doSave() {
            var txtFirstName = document.getElementById("txtFirstName");
            var txtLastName = document.getElementById("txtLastName");
            var txtAddress = document.getElementById("txtAddress");
            var txtEmail = document.getElementById("txtEmail");
            var txtContact = document.getElementById("txtContact");
            var txtBirthDate = document.getElementById("txtBirthDate");
            console.log(txtFirstName.value);
            console.log(txtLastName.value);

            var obj = { "FirstName": txtFirstName.value, "LastName": txtLastName.value, "Address": txtAddress.value, "Email": txtEmail.value, "Contact": txtContact.value, "BirthDate": txtBirthDate.value };
            studentList.push(obj);

            loadData();
            // document.getElementById("registrationfrm").reset();
        }

       
        function loadData() {
            var str = "";
            for (let i = 0; i < studentList.length; i++) {
                var obj = studentList[i];
                var FullName = obj.FirstName + " " + obj.LastName;
                str = str + "<tr><td>" + FullName + "</td><td>" + obj.Address + "</td><td>" + obj.Email + "</td><td>" + obj.Contact + "</td><td>" + obj.BirthDate + "</td><td class=''><button class='btn-xs btn-info btn-operation col-6'><i class='fa fa-edit'></i></button><button class='col-6 btn-xs btn-danger btn-operation' clickon='DeleteItem(" + i + ")'><i class='fa fa-trash' ></i></button></td></tr>";

            }
            document.getElementById("tblBody").innerHTML = str;

        }

        function DeleteItem(index) {
            var d = confirm("Do You want to delete?")
            if (d == true) {
                studentList.splice(index, 1)
                loadData();
            }

        }
        function doClear() {
            txtFirstName.style = "";
            txtLastName.style = "";
            txtAddress.style = "";
            txtEmail.style = "";
            txtContact.style = "";
            txtBirthDate.style = "";
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container-fluid ">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4 bg-info">
                <form id="registrationfrm" class="row" action="" method="post">
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <label for="" class="form-label">First Name<span class="compulsory">*</span></label>
                        <input type="text" name="" id="txtFirstName" class="form-control">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <label for="" class="form-label">Last Name<span class="compulsory">*</span></label>
                        <input type="text" name="" id="txtLastName" class="form-control">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-12">
                        <label for="" class="form-label">Address<span class="compulsory">*</span></label>
                        <textarea class="form-control" id="txtAddress"></textarea>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-12">
                        <label for="" class="form-label">Email Address<span class="compulsory">*</span></label>
                        <input type="email" name="" id="txtEmail" class="form-control" placeholder="example@email.com">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-12">
                        <label for="" class="form-label">Contact No<span class="compulsory">*</span></label>
                        <input type="number" name="" id="txtContact" class="form-control">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-12">
                        <label for="" class="form-label">Date of Birth<span class="compulsory">*</span></label>
                        <input type="date" name="" id="txtBirthDate" class="form-control">
                    </div>
                    <div class="text-center">
                        <button type="reset" class="btn btn-outline-dark align-items-center" onclick="doClear()">Clear
                            All</button>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-dark align-items-center"
                            onclick="doSave()">Save</button>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
            <div class="container-fluid col-md-8">
                <div class=" bg-light w-100">
                    <table class="table table-bordered border-primary">
                        <thead class="table-dark text-center">
                            <th>Full Name</th>
                            <th>Address</th>
                            <th>Email Address</th>
                            <th>Contact No</th>
                            <th>Birth Date</th>
                            <th>Operation</th>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody id="tblBody">
<!-- <button  onclick="DeleteItem(1)">Delete</button> -->
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: The click handler should be set on the `onclick` attribute and not on `clickon`. Be also careful because the values are not escaped! This can lead to HTML injection so to XSS attacks. See what happens if you enter `<strong>My firstname</strong>` to see what I mean.

Comment: You may also add some validation on the form before inserting. This can be done with [HTML5 validation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Forms/Form_validation) and some JS checks in your `doSave()` function.

Answer (score 2):

There is a typo mistake:

```
clickon='DeleteItem(" + i + ")'
```

Should be

```
onclick='DeleteItem(" + i + ")'
```